# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [air bag light after seat removal repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/air-bag-light-after-seat-removal-repair)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Motorcycle chain degreasing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11420/motorcycle-chain-degreasing)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What to do when antifreeze is in the oil casing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11502/what-to-do-when-antifreeze-is-in-the-oil-casing)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I access the signal from the wheel speed sensors?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11513/can-i-access-the-signal-from-the-wheel-speed-sensors)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's wrong with my pressure washer?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11391/whats-wrong-with-my-pressure-washer)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [wheel/pulley coming out of my engine is making a loud rattling noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11664/wheel-pulley-coming-out-of-my-engine-is-making-a-loud-rattling-noise)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Caliper guide pin position on 2001 Mitsubishi Eclipse Sdyder GT Conv](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11403/2001-mitsubishi-eclipse-sdyder-gt-conv)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [A/C causes the the car to die](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/a-c-causes-the-the-car-to-die)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is leaving either a metric or an imperial wrench set in a GM vehicle sufficient for all (most) emergency repairs?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11551/is-leaving-either-a-metric-or-an-imperial-wrench-set-in-a-gm-vehicle-sufficient)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Audi A4 B5 (1995) climate control/heater/blower problem](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/audi-a4-b5-1995-climate-control-heater-blower-problem)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---